# Composition API with Nuxt 2 to get template refs array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to get the array of element refs that are not in `v-for`. I'm using `@nuxtjs/composition-api` on Nuxt 2.

(Truth: I want to make an array of input elements, so that I can perform validations on them before submit)

This sounds too easy on vue 2 as `$refs` becomes an array when one or more compnents have the same ref name on html. However, this doesn't sound simple with composition api and trying to perform simple task with that got me stuck from long.

So to handle this scenario, I've created 1 composable function. (Soruce: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/array-refs.html#frontmatter-title)

```
// file: viewRefs.js

import { onBeforeUpdate, onUpdated } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
export default () => {
  let itemRefs = []
  const setItemRef = el => {
    console.log('adding item ref')
    if (el) {
      itemRefs.push(el)
    }
  }
  onBeforeUpdate(() => {
    itemRefs = []
  })
  onUpdated(() => {
    console.log(itemRefs)
  })
  return {
    itemRefs,
    setItemRef
  }
}
```

Here is my `vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input :ref="input.setItemRef" />
    <input :ref="input.setItemRef" />
    <input :ref="input.setItemRef" />
    <input :ref="input.setItemRef" />
    <input :ref="input.setItemRef" />
    <input :ref="input.setItemRef" />
    // rest of my cool html
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  defineComponent,
  reactive,
  useRouter,
  ref
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
import viewRefs from '~/composables/viewRefs'
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {

    const input = viewRefs()

    // awesome vue code here...
   
    return {
      input
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Now when I run this file, I don't see any `adding item ref` logs. And on click of a button, I'm logging `input`. That has 0 items in the `itemRefs` array.

What's going wrong?

Comment: `itemRefs = []` is incorrect because you reassign local variable. Make it `ref` and never reassign.

Comment: @EstusFlask Made it ref and used `itemRefs.value.push`, but still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nuxt 2 is based on Vue 2, which only accepts strings for the [`ref` attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref). The [docs you linked](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/array-refs.html#frontmatter-title) actually refer to new behavior in Vue 3 for [`ref`, where functions are also accepted](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/special-attributes.html#ref).

Template refs in Nuxt 2 work the same way as they do in Vue 2 with Composition API: When a `ref` is inside a `v-for`, the `ref` becomes an array:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="logRefs">Log refs</button>
    <input v-for="i in 4" :key="i" ref="itemRef" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default {
  setup() {
    const itemRef = ref(null)
    return {
      itemRef,
      logRefs() {
        console.log(itemRef.value) // => array of inputs
      },
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67705419/6277151)

And `setup()` does not provide access to `$refs`, as [template refs must be explicitly declared as reactive `ref`s in Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#template-refs).